# Complexity of searching for intersection between grids with RTrees

Tags: performance, boost, tree, intersection, space-complexity

I have two grids (coming from finite elements, but this is not relevant), say `T_1`, `T_2`. One grid is inside the other, think of a square inside another one for instance. For each grid I have constructed an RTree with `boost` of bounding boxes, say `RTree1` and `RTree2`. To find all the pair of intersecting rectangles, I do the following

```
for (const auto &[box2, cell2] : RTree_2)
      {
        for (const auto &[box1, cell1] :
             RTree1 | bgi::adaptors::queried(bgi::intersects(box2)))
          {
             do_something_with_cells(cell1,cell2);

          }
      }
  }
```

Let's say that I have `N` bounding boxes for the first tree and `M` bounding boxes for the second tree. I want to determine the complexity of the snippet above.
Since the intersection has a complexity which is `O(log(N))` (on average), I think the snippet above has a complexity which is `O(N M log(N))`. Is this correct?

---

If the code above was written like this:

```
for (const auto &[box2, cell2] : RTree_2)
      {
        for (const auto &[box1, cell1] :
             RTree1)
          {
             //check if box1 and box2 intersects using bgi
             bgi::query(box1,bgi::intersects(box2));
          }
      }
  }
```

I should have a `O(NM log(N))`, right?

Comment: If these rectangles are in a grid, it would be much simpler to assign cells ids instead of doing calculating geometrical intersections. Can you paint a sample picture of e.g. RTree1 so we can understand better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since the intersection has a complexity which is O(log(N))

What intersection are you talking about here? If you're talking about the entirety of the `query` (which seems to make most sense due to your inclusion of `N`), then you should not have to multiply `N` again outside the query. I think it is `O(M log(N)` therefore.

Comment: I'm talking about the query in the second for. In practice, I test for intersections each pair of boxes, using (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/boost__geometry__index__rtree/query_predicates_const____outiter_.html#classboost_1_1geometry_1_1index_1_1rtree_1ace0ba7f3280b1074cea31b4f1bc1d7ea). Since each query is 'O(log(N))', I should find a 'O(NM log(N))', isn't it? @sehe

Comment: Where do you get the second `N` in `NM`? The query is only executed once in [ranged-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for#Explanation). To see how that pans out: https://cppinsights.io/s/3cc60073 (click the "Play" button or hit Ctrl-Enter)

Comment: Maybe I found my mistake. I edited my question. Basically, using the range for with the `operator |` is improving the performances w.r.t the second snippet I wrote in the question. Is this correct? @sehe

Comment: Yes, the query uses the tree structure to optimize. Worst case it would be similar perf (when everything overlaps or when the tree is packed suboptimally). In practice it can matter quite a bit to swap the loops around if e.g. N ⋙ M or when you know one tree is better packed/contains more disjoint shapes than the other.

Comment: Thanks so much @sehe, I see what you mean. So if I use a filter I have on average  `O(N log(N))` in time, while with two for loops + the query inside (see edited question) inside I have a `O(N M log(N))`, correct?

Comment: Yes. Although it's not depending on the adaptor form. It's depending on the use of the indexing query algorithm. In other words, all the following will have similar performance: https://godbolt.org/z/qdaonP1Pj