# Are filtered iterator loops (with boost) faster than classical for loop with an if condition inside

Tags: c++, performance, filter, boost, c++14

I'm a C++ newbie, and I'm trying to understand some boost capabilities. Looking at the top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38399334/how-can-i-avoid-for-loops-with-an-if-condition-inside-them-with-c), I've seen this snippet:

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/filtered.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct is_even
{
    bool operator()( int x ) const { return x % 2 == 0; }
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    using namespace boost::adaptors;

    std::vector<int> myCollection{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    for( int i: myCollection | filtered( is_even() ) )
    {
        std::cout << i;
    }
}
```

Is there any advantage in terms of complexity w.r.t the classical approach, i.e. the for loop plus an if condition inside it? If so, how is that possible? I don't see the rationale behind it.

Comment: Seems like the opposite is the case: At least clang seems to optimize out the filtering in the "standard implementation", see https://godbolt.org/z/47jPo8v3h vs https://godbolt.org/z/E7Kn7xPao  Regardless of the compiler it's unlikely that the more complex logic provided by boost offers a better degree of optimization potential compared the simpler logic using only a for loop + `if`. The only benefit of using the boost logic here is that is some people may consider it to be more pleasant to the eye(I don't), aid with template programming, or ....

Comment: It's amazing how often a compiler does a much better with simpler, stupider, more-obvious code.

Comment: @fabian Uhm, then I don't understand the following. In this question I asked, (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73695420/complexity-of-searching-for-intersection-between-grids-with-rtrees) what I understand from the answer is that this filtering in improving *a lot* the complexity in space. Isn't it? Or am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: Ranges are not working on temporary container improving the efficiency of memory-bound codes and reducing the memory footprint. The range-based version is meant to produce a code with an if-based version here once optimized. That being said, it makes use of temporary functions and data structure that make the code much more complex to optimize for compilers. Thus, such code is sometime slower than doing the job manually. The thing is range-based code can make code more maintainable and ease composition of algorithm, especially when the composed codes are non trivial (ie. not here).

Comment: A good example a range-based code is a C compilers front-end parser: a first step deal with newlines, another one do the tokenization, another the preprocessing, another build the AST. Building temporary string/vector-of-tokens/AST would not be efficient. Ranges can be used to merge all that steps in an efficient 1-step algorithm while each step can be maintained separately. Writing 1 big algorithm is insane (bug-prone and the naive manual implementation tends not to be as efficient than the range-based version).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any advantage in terms of complexity w.r.t the classical approach, i.e. the for loop plus an if condition inside it?

No. You can compare the code gen as people have showed you in the comments.

> Uhm, then I don't understand the following. In this question I asked [...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73721318/are-filtered-iterator-loops-with-boost-faster-than-classical-for-loop-with-an/73723068#comment130181895_73721318)

Picking the origin of the question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73695420/complexity-of-searching-for-intersection-between-grids-with-rtrees#comment130180206_73700220):

> Thanks so much @sehe, I see what you mean. So if I use a filter I have on average O(N log(N)) in time, while with two for loops + the query inside (see edited question) inside I have a O(N M log(N)), correct?

I answered:

> Yes. Although it's not depending on the adaptor form. It's depending on the use of the indexing query algorithm. In other words, all the following will have similar performance: https://godbolt.org/z/qdaonP1Pj

The point is **not** the range-adaptor. The point is the algorithm.

The `bgi::query` algorithm does **not** iterate through elements linearly.

Instead, *[the query uses...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73695420/complexity-of-searching-for-intersection-between-grids-with-rtrees#:%7E:text=the%20query%20uses%20the%20tree%20structure%20to%20optimize) the tree structure to optimize. Worst case it would be similar perf (when everything overlaps or when the tree is packed suboptimally). In practice it can matter quite a bit to swap the loops around if e.g. N ⋙ M or when you know one tree is better packed/contains more disjoint shapes than the other.*

Key to the optimization is that rtree is a datastructure with specific knowledge of geometrical relations, not just a vector.

### Summary

The loop-form isn't the big factor. It's *what you iterate over* that's optimized by bgi::query. The following should al have similar (if not identical) performance:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/qdaonP1Pj)**

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/function_output_iterator.hpp>
namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;
using bgi::adaptors::queried;

void do_something_with_cells(int a, int b) {
    std::cout << "Intersect: " << a << " and " << b << "\n";
}

using P = bg::model::d2::point_xy<int>;
using B = bg::model::box<P>;
using T = bgi::rtree<std::pair<B, int>, bgi::rstar<16> >;

static constexpr std::array data = {
    std::pair(B{{0, 0},  {4,  4}}, 1),
    std::pair(B{{3, 3},  {7,  7}}, 2),
    std::pair(B{{6, 6}, {10, 10}}, 3),
    std::pair(B{{9, 9}, {13, 13}}, 4),
};

int main() {
    for (auto& [b, _] : data)
        if (std::string r; !bg::is_valid(b, r))
            std::cout << bg::wkt(b) << ": " << r << "\n";

    bgi::rtree<std::pair<B, int>, bgi::rstar<16> > a, b;
    a.insert(data.begin(), data.end());
    b.insert(data[1]);
    b.insert(data[3]);

    auto exercise = [](T const& t1, T const& t2) 
    {
        std::cout << "Classic iterators\n";
        for (auto& [box2, cell2] : t2) {
            auto f = bgi::qbegin(t1, bgi::intersects(box2)), l = bgi::qend(t1);
            for (; f != l; ++f) {
                do_something_with_cells(f->second, cell2);
            }
        }

        std::cout << "Output iterator\n";
        for (auto& [box2, cell2] : t2) {
            bgi::query( //
                t1, bgi::intersects(box2),
                boost::function_output_iterator([cell2 = cell2](auto& pair) {
                    do_something_with_cells(pair.second, cell2);
                }));
        }

        std::cout << "Range adaptor\n";
        for (auto& [box2, cell2] : t2) {
            for (auto& [bmatch, cmatch] : t1 | queried(bgi::intersects(box2))) {
                do_something_with_cells(cmatch, cell2);
            }
        }
    };

    exercise(a, b);
    exercise(b, a);
}
```

Printing

```
Classic iterators
Intersect: 1 and 2
Intersect: 2 and 2
Intersect: 3 and 2
Intersect: 3 and 4
Intersect: 4 and 4
Output iterator
Intersect: 1 and 2
Intersect: 2 and 2
Intersect: 3 and 2
Intersect: 3 and 4
Intersect: 4 and 4
Range adaptor
Intersect: 1 and 2
Intersect: 2 and 2
Intersect: 3 and 2
Intersect: 3 and 4
Intersect: 4 and 4
Classic iterators
Intersect: 2 and 1
Intersect: 2 and 2
Intersect: 2 and 3
Intersect: 4 and 3
Intersect: 4 and 4
Output iterator
Intersect: 2 and 1
Intersect: 2 and 2
Intersect: 2 and 3
Intersect: 4 and 3
Intersect: 4 and 4
Range adaptor
Intersect: 2 and 1
Intersect: 2 and 2
Intersect: 2 and 3
Intersect: 4 and 3
Intersect: 4 and 4
```

---

¹ As I hinted before, in certain worst case there might be a slight overhead over just linearly iterating.